# How to display the clicked email when using jsp for loop to display all the emails from database

Tags: jsp, email, jdbc

Hi I am making this code to display the contents of the email from a database. Each email is an entry of an array. This code below is just the inbox and when the user clicks on the title he is redirected to mailClick.jsp . But the problem is when we click on the email, we dont know which email has the user clicked on so the value of i in the for loop is not stored or in other words we dont know which mail has the user clicked on. Please help me out. Can there be a way to get the value of i on which the user has clicked? Or any other way?

```
<div class="wrapper row5">
    <%

    Home home = new Home();
    int length = home.countMail(user);  
    Email[] newMail = home.getMail(user);

    %>

   <table align = "center" class = "email">

    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#282828; color:white;"> Sender </td>
        <td style="background-color:#282828; color:white;"> Title </td>
        <td style="background-color:#282828; color:white;"> Date </td>
        <td style="background-color:#282828; color:white;"> Time </td>


    </tr>

<%

if(length>0){

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {%>
    <tr>

        <td> <%=home.getName(newMail[i].getSender())  %> </td>
        <td> <form action = ""></form><a href="mailClick.jsp"><b><%=newMail[i].getTitle() %></b></a></td>
        <td> <%=newMail[i].getDate() %></td>
        <td> <%=newMail[i].getTime() %></td>

    </tr>

<%} 

}%>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `Email` class has an unique `id` property, you can do

```
<td>
  <a href="mailClick.jsp?id=<%= newMail[i].getId() %>">
    <b><%= newMail[i].getTitle() %></b>
  </a>
</td>
```

and then, in `mailClick.jsp`, retrieve this ID (`String id = request.getParameter("id");`) and use it to get the requested image.